# external monitor no longer recognized when connected VGA, freezed computer when connected with HDMI

Tags: 13.10, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, vga

I'm using 13.04 on a thinkpad X230.  I had routinely used a VGA cable to plug in my external ASUS monitor.  when entering the "disply" app, ubuntu would recognize it as "ancor communications", and give appropriate resolution options.  I set it on its side, set the display to clockwise, and used it as a vertical monitor for months without problems.

all of a sudden, for no reason I can tell, it stops working.  When I plug it in, it is no longer recognized as an "ancor communications" monitor, and it only gives me really coarse resolution options, which are useless.

I fished out a HDMI cable and plugged that in.  Lo and behold it recognizes the brand of the monitor, and looks sharp and nice.  But after about 5 minutes of being plugged in the computer starts to get reaaaaallllly slooooooow.  I unplug and everything seems fine, but I have no external monitor.

Why did this break and how do I either make my external monitor recognizable through VGA (as it was before) or not crash in HDMI (which would be nice)??

Thanks for any help.  I have no idea why this doesn't just work as it did before.

**Edit1:**  Added the bounty yesterday because I really want to fix this and I have no idea how to do it.  I'll award answers that both fix the problem and explain why the fix works.

**Edit2:**  Here is the output of `xrandr -q verbose`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2134 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (0x4d) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 277mm x 156mm
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  54199073
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004ca3473000000000
        00140103801c1078ea1d859156598f26
        18505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101381d56d4500016303020
        2500159c100000190000000f00000000
        000000000025d9066a00000000fe0053
        414d53554e470a204ca34154000000fe
        004c544e31323541543031343031005d
    BACKLIGHT: 15 
        range: (0, 15)
    Backlight: 15 
        range: (0, 15)
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: NoneFullCenterFull aspect
  1366x768 (0x4d)   74.8MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1366 start 1414 end 1446 total 1578 skew    0 clock   47.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  770 end  775 total  790           clock   60.0Hz
  1360x768 (0xb3)   84.8MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock   47.7KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock   59.8Hz
  1360x768 (0xb4)   72.0MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock   47.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock   60.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x4e)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0xb5)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0xb6)   36.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
  640x480 (0xb7)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
VGA1 connected 768x1024+1366+0 (0x4e) right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  54199073
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
  1024x768 (0x4e)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync *current
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0xb5)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0xb6)   36.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
  848x480 (0xb8)   33.8MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   848 start  864 end  976 total 1088 skew    0 clock   31.0KHz
        v: height  480 start  486 end  494 total  517           clock   60.0Hz
  640x480 (0xb9)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x45
    Timestamp:  54199073
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: AutomaticFullLimited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvioffautoon
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x46
    Timestamp:  54199073
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: AutomaticFullLimited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvioffautoon
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x47
    Timestamp:  54199073
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: AutomaticFullLimited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvioffautoon
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x48
    Timestamp:  54199073
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: AutomaticFullLimited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvioffautoon
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x49
    Timestamp:  54199073
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: AutomaticFullLimited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvioffautoon
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x4a
    Timestamp:  54199073
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: AutomaticFullLimited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvioffautoon
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x4b
    Timestamp:  54199073
    Subpixel:   no subpixels
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter:
```

Comment: also, will this be fixed somehow if I upgrade to 13.10?

Comment: This either sounds like a hardware problem or an update that might've introduced a regression. Did this happen after you installed some updates? Also which kernel version are you running?

Comment: same here since I upgraded to 13.10!!!

Comment: Regarding the HDMI out problem I think that it is a bug. From [debian](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Thinkpad/X230/wheezy): "*With the 3.2 kernel currently in wheezy, the system occasionally freezes completely. It does so very soon if you attempt to drive a 30" Dual-DVI external monitor through the Mini ~DisplayPort++.*"

Comment: When you plug-in the external through VGA, what is the output of `xrandr -q --verbose`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `xrandr` output it looks like the X server doesn't get the EDID info from your monitor either because of your monitor has a hardware failure or it is a driver bug.

You should try the solutions presented in the [ARCH wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Troubleshooting), under the **Adding undetected resolutions** title.

And if it does solve your problem, then just make a script from the commands you had to run, i.e. open your favourite text editor and make a file like below (of course **change the xrandr command parameters** to those which worked for you):

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024_60.00
```

Save it in `/etc/vga_setup.sh` (You will need root privileges to save it here, but if you want you can save it anywhere you want.) Then make it executable: `sudo chmod a+x /etc/vga_setup.sh` Test the file if it works: in a terminal simply `/etc/vga_setup.sh` If it works, no errors reported, then:

Open `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` in your favourite text editor (you will need root privileges so use sudo or gksu), and add these lines to the end of the file:

```
display-setup-script = /etc/vga_setup.sh
session-setup-script = /etc/vga_setup.sh
```

Save the file. Reboot. Should work. (If after reboot your GUI doesn't come up don't afraid, just switch to virtual console (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), login, and remove the added lines from the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file and reboot, then come back here.)

Comment: The thing from arch wiki worked!  I'll award the bounty if it still works tomorrow.

Comment: It no longer recognizes the manual changes that I made after I restart my computer.  How can I "just make a script from the commands I had to run"??  I do not know how to make a shell script.

Comment: @ACD Updated the answer. I think it is detailed enough now. I have to go to sleep so if problems come up I can only react tomorrow, but I'm sure others will help here too. (But there shouldn't be any more problems.)

Comment: @ACD Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: It works!  For posterity, the system was somehow unhappy about running the shell script after making the changes manually.  I got it to work by doing it manually -> rebooting -> doing the shell script stuff -> rebooting